# Nginx start fail with no errors

Tags: nginx

I can't start my nginx (1.6.2) on Debian using `service nginx start.` I have 0 error, only `FAIL` as message.

I checked my config using `nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf -t` and it's successfull.

I have built nginx from source, I have installed pagespeed module.

It seems I have the same error from here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24961066/cant-start-nginx-no-errors-anywhere
But after checked, both files are looking for `/run/nginx.pid.` This file seems to be empty thought, is this a problem ?

`ls -al /run/*.pid` give me :

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 nov.  26 09:32 /run/nginx.pid
```

When I use `ps -A`, I have 2 nginx with 2 pid differents. Is this the problem ?

Something weird too, when I access my IP in web browser, I have the "Welcome to Ningx" message. But, `service nginx status` returns FAIL.

Comment: `ps ax | grep nginx` ?

Answer (score 0):

Having several nginx process might be normal... or not. If you only have 2 processes, then you probably have the master process and 1 worker process, which is the way nginx works. Having several master processes, unless it is what you wish, is probably sign of trouble.

If your PID file is empty, that is definitely a problem: it is used by the managing service to identify which process to check for and to send signals to. Empty PID file = service will try to send signals to the void...

1. Using `ps -ef|grep -E "(PID|nginx)"|grep -v grep`, try to identify the master process (that is the one with PPID 1 and calling itself 'master in its description). Then send it a TERM, KILL or QUIT signal.
2. Manually remove the PID file
3. Check your service file (if you use init, it is most probably `/etc/init.d/nginx`) for the PID file name and compare it to the location you provided
4. Ensure no PID file is there, no nginx process runs anymore and use your service normally to start/stop/reload/check status again.

That should do it.

Now, where does that empty PID file comes from is an interesting question one could ask him/herself... Have you played around with it? Multiple instances of nginx does not apply for it, you should have something there!